# Explicit map from countable subset of $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: order-theory

Let $A\subsetneq[0,1]$ be some countable set of real numbers. Since the rationals are dense in the reals and since all countable linear orders are embeddable into $\mathbb{Q}$, it seems to me that there has to be a map $f:A\rightarrow[0,1]_\mathbb{Q}$ with $[0,1]_\mathbb{Q}$ being the rational interval such that for any $a\in A$:
$$a\leq a'\text{ iff }f(a)\leq f(a')$$

Is it possible to construct $f$ explicitly, without resorting to the axiom of choice?

---

$f$ *does not* have to be onto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my limited understanding of set theory, you can do this with induction without using any variant of the axiom of choice at all.

Since $A$ is countable, you are assuming there exists some enumeration of its elements $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.  Start with the empty map mapping the empty subset of $A$ to an empty subset of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.  The induction step is assuming you already have a mapping of $a_1,...,a_k$ to some rationals in this interval $b_1, ..., b_k$ that preserves the linear order.  To perform the induction step you need to choose a rational to send $a_{k+1}$ to.  Ok.  There's a unique pair $a_s, a_t$ such that $s, t \le k$, $a_s$ and $a_t$ are adjacent in the linear order and $a_{k+1}$ is between them.  So Let $b_{k+1} = (b_s+b_t)/2$.  You need to handle the case where $a_{k+1}$ is to the left, or right of all $\{a_1, ..., a_k\}$ and make sure you don't go beyond the interval $[0,1]$.  I'll let you complete the detail, but the point is there is no use of the axiom of choice because you're giving an algorithm how to choose $b_{k+1}$.
To finish the proof, you take the **union** of all finite partial maps you constructed this way to get a complete mapping of $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: $A$ doesn't have to be well-ordered. But we want our map to be order-preserving…

Comment: @Daniil: I think you misunderstood me.  The enumeration $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not order preserving.  You preserve the order while constructing the sequence $b_n$ by giving an algorithm how to select the next $b$.  That's all you need.  If the selection of next $b$ is deterministic, you're avoiding the axiom of choice.  Taking the union doesn't require choice either.  It uses the axiom of union, possible the axiom of replacement to argue that the range of the mapping is a set.

Comment: Since $A$ is countable, it can be well ordered (though this will not coincide with the order induced from $A\subset \mathbb R$). @user941248 uses this to build $f$ by induction (without AC)

Comment: I don't get the "left to the reader part". Which is, for me, the most unclear. How we chose $b_{k+1}$ when $a_{k+1}$ is on the left or right of the previous induction set at k? It is enough to just take the max or the min of the set of b_k's and find the middle point between the endpoints of the rational unit interval? Is that that your hinting at?

Comment: @MphLee: When $a_{k+1}$ is to the left of all previous $a$-s, find $a_s$ which is the leftmost and let $b_{k+1} = b_s/2$.  Similarly on the right take $(1+b_s)/2$ for the rightmost $a_s$.  You can start the induction by taking $b_1 = 1/2$ and this avoids using the endpoints $0, 1$ altogether and keeps the $b$-s all in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is not possible, in general, since $0$ and $1$ are rational numbers in $[0,1]$ which are smaller (resp. larger then all others). you will not have this numbers for $A$ in general.

Comment: Why? Of course, $f(0)=0_\mathbb{Q}$ and likewise for $f(1)$, no? Or did I mistype something? And if neither $0$, nor $1$ is in $A$ then we just don't map anything to them… No? And $f$ does not have to be onto…

Comment: I think @crank thought, like I did at first, that you required $f$ to be a bijection.